# Dynamically updating icons with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm coding a simple accordion using HTML5 and jQuery to animate the opening and closing states.

I want to visually show users when sections of the accordion are opened or closed using font awesome icons. At the moment I have managed to achieve this using the following code below:

```
$(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa fa-plus-circle fa fa-minus-circle')
```

The only issue that I'm having trouble figuring out how to reset each sections icon to the plus icon when not in an open state. For example, if I click Item 1 the icon will now change from a plus to a minus, great! But that problem is if I click on Item 2 or 3 the icon will not revert back to a plus.

[image]

As I have illustrated in the above screenshot, this is what I'm trying to achieve. I have used Item 1 and 3 as examples but it should work the same way for all the Items.

I've provided a [JSFiddle with my syntax](http://jsfiddle.net/6gu22t9j/), and here's the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';
    $('.accordian h3').click(function () {
        //toggle plus and minus icons
        $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa fa-plus-circle fa fa-minus-circle');
        //slide up all the list items
        $('.accordian ul ul').slideUp();
        //slide down the list itmes below the h3 clicked - only if it's closed
        if (!$(this).next().is(':visible')) {
            $(this).next().slideDown();
        }
    });
});
```

```css
@import url("http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");
html, body {
    background-color: #ccc
}
.accordian {
 margin: 0 auto;
 color: #000;
}
.accordian h3 {
 padding: 15px;
    line-height: 1px;
 cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #000;
 -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
/*iconfont styles*/
.accordian h3 i {
    font-size: 18px;
 margin-right: 10px;
}
.accordian li {
 list-style-type: none;
}
/*Lets hide the non active li's by default*/
.accordian ul ul {
 display: none;
}
.accordian li.active ul {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
 <div class="accordian">
     <ul>
         <li>
             <h3><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>Item 1</h3>
             <ul>
                 <li>
                     Item 1
                 </li>
             </ul>
         </li>
         <li>
             <h3><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>Item 2</h3>
             <ul>
                 <li>
                     Item 2
                 </li>
             </ul>
         </li>
         <li>
             <h3><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>Item 3</h3>
             <ul>
                 <li>
                     Item 3
                 </li>
             </ul>
         </li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';
    $('.accordian h3').click(function () {
        //toggle plus and minus icons
        $('.accordian h3 i').addClass('fa-plus-circle').removeClass('fa-minus-circle');
        $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa fa-plus-circle fa fa-minus-circle');
        //slide up all the list items
        $('.accordian ul ul').slideUp();
        //slide down the list itmes below the h3 clicked - only if it's closed
        if (!$(this).next().is(':visible')) {
            $(this).next().slideDown();
        }else{
            $('.accordian h3 i').addClass('fa-plus-circle').removeClass('fa-minus-circle');
        }
    });
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6gu22t9j/1/)

Comment: Hello Mohamed, I appreciate your response however the only problem I'm having now is when I click on an item, and then click the same item again it does does toggle back to a plus?

Comment: @Jordan check the jsfiddle in my answer its already doing that

Comment: Yes, I have just noticed that you had updated your response and it working as should now. I had tried using the .addClass and .removeClass but in the wrong places, thank you very much for the help though, great job!